# Apache BeanUtils : create dynamic bean from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, apache, servlets, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I am using this code to create dynamic bean out of the result set -

```
RowSetDynaClass rsdc = new RowSetDynaClass(rset,false,1);
List row = rsdc.getRows();
DynaBean bean = (DynaBean) row.get(0);
```

This work's great- but i'm unable to find a way to get `DynaBean` from request parameter's passed in `HttpServletRequest`.

How can i create dynamic bean from `HttpServletRequest` object ?

[DOCS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html)

[This](http://slim3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/slim3/javadoc/org/slim3/util/BeanUtil.html) is what i want, but it's in a different api (*not in apache beanutils*)

Answer (score 0):

I got the working solution -

```
BeanUtils.populate(myBean, request.getParameterMap());
```